# Python 3.x for loops and list indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm having trouble understanding, this simple question using for loop in Python, which I found in an online quiz. Can you please help me understand, why we are getting the below output?

```
some_list = [1,2,3,4,5]

for some_list[1] in some_list:
    print(some_list)
    print(some_list[1])
```

output:

```
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5]
1
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5]
1
[1, 3, 3, 4, 5]
3
[1, 4, 3, 4, 5]
4
[1, 5, 3, 4, 5]
5
```

I thought, it would print the 2nd element of the list and the whole list 5 times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `for x in some_list:` loops through a list and temporarily stores each value of the list in `x`.

The expression `for some_list[1] in some_list:` loops through a list and temporarily stores each value of the list in `some_list[1]`. (Each iteration of the loop, the next value of the list is over-writing `some_list[1]`.)

> I thought, it would print the 2nd element of the list and the whole list 5 times.

That is what's happening, it's just that the list is changing (particularly the 2nd element).

Comment: That's a nice explanation. I don't understand why the elements in the original list keep changing with each print? 

Does the value of some_list[1] gets updated with the temp value while reading for x in the loop?

Comment: @ParvBanks Yes, that element of the list is changing each time the loop pulls a temp value.